# For loop and if statement to copy in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, macros

I am currently trying to check cells from 2 columns (one for loop for each) and see whether they have the string true. If yes I would like to copy some cells corresponding, to another sheet(log).

I know that I have some cells, which contain the word true but when I run the program there is nothing that is copied in my other sheet.

I do not get any compiling errors and would like to know where I am wrong in this code.

```
Sub isLimit()

    Dim a As Long, b As Long, Lr As Long

    x = 2
    y = 2
    Lr = Worksheets("Targets").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 8 To Lr
    If (StrComp(Cells(i, 15).Text, "TRUE")) = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Log").Range("B" & x) = "no"
    x = x + 1
    End If
    Next i

    For j = 8 To Lr
    If (StrComp(Cells(j, 16).Text, "TRUE")) = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Log").Range("B2") = Worksheets("Targets").Range("B1").Value
    Worksheets("Log").Range("C" & y) = "yes"
    y = y + 1
    End If
    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I can see two problems that might causing you the trouble.

1.Since you are not setting which sheets to be checked from line below,

It will check for the activesheet cells i,15 then return -1 or 0 (true or false).

Which will only work when your screen displays sheet where data is stored.

```
If (StrComp(Cells(i, 15).Text, "TRUE")) = 0 Then
```

2.If your DATA contains something else then TRUE (for example space before or after the value).

It might see it as something other than "TRUE"

That's all I can tell without looking at your actual data.